# Fibonacci using OOP methods in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, fibonacci-sequence

I made a simple program that uses OOP methods. Please tell me if I used the 4 methods right. And if not, please show me how.

```
class Encap{
    private String name;
    public void setName(String newValue){
        name = "Hello, "+newValue+"!";
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

abstract class Abstraction {
    int fibCount, flag=0, y;
    String inputName;
    String names[] = new String [] {"Anna","Joe","Carl"};
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
abstract void abscompute();
}

class abs2 extends Abstraction{
    @Override
    void abscompute() 
    {
         System.out.print("Enter number of fibonacci: ");
         fibCount = x.nextInt();
         int[] fib = new int[fibCount];
         fib[0] = 0;
         fib[1] = 1;
         for(int i=2; i < fibCount; i++){
             fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
         }

         for(int i=0; i< fibCount; i++){
                 System.out.print(fib[i] + " ");

                }

    }
}
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abstraction abs = new abs2();
        Encap encap = new Encap();
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        abs.inputName = abs.x.next();
        for (String name : abs.names) {
            if(abs.inputName.equals(name)){
                encap.setName(abs.inputName);
                System.out.println(""+encap.getName());
                abs.flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(abs.flag!=1){
            System.out.println("Name doesn't exist..");
        }
        else{
            abs.abscompute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> class Encap{
> ```

I find all your class names confusing.  You seem to be describing the code, not what it does.  Maybe something like

```
class Greeter {
```

would be more understandable.

> ```
>     private String name;
>     public void setName(String newValue){
>         name = "Hello, "+newValue+"!";
>     }
> ```

The `name` variable isn't a name, but a greeting.  Why not call it that?

Also, `newValue` isn't very descriptive.  That actually is a name, so

```
    private String greeting;

    public void setGreeting(String name) {
        greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
```

Now I can easily see that `setGreeting` takes a name as an input.

Some people might argue that `setGreeting` should only set the greeting, not determine what it is.  You could either create a constructor to handle this with an immutable variable, or you could change the name to `changeGreeting`.  Or you can ignore that convention, but you may get negative feedback.

> ```
> abstract class Abstraction {
> ```

This could be

```
abstract class Sequence {

    private int[] sequence;

    Sequence(int length) {
        sequence = new int[length];
    }

    int getLength() {
        return sequence.length;
    }

    abstract void generate();
}
```

This seems a clearer set of names.

You also may want to look into how to use constructors

> ```
>     int fibCount, flag=0, y;
> ```

It's generally preferable to have one variable per declaration, particularly if you are initializing as well.

```
    int fibCount;
    int flag = 0;
    int y;
```

Now you can easily see that only `flag` is initialized.

Why declare `y`?  You never use it.

Why make `fibCount` and `flag` object fields?  You only use them in one method.  They could be local variables instead.

> ```
>     String names[] = new String [] {"Anna","Joe","Carl"};
> ```

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the rest of this.  Why declare that variable in this class?

> ```
>     Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
> ```

Why name your `Scanner` `x`?  Is it a secret that it is a scanner?  More common names would be `scan` or `scanner`.  You could also name it something like `input` or `stdin`.

I'd move the input and output out of the class and into `main`.  Then you can make `scanner` a local variable as well.

> ```
> class abs2 extends Abstraction{
> ```

Again, this would be clearer as

```
class FibonacciSequence extends Sequence {
```

Now I know what I expect to find here.

> ```
>         for (String name : abs.names) {
>             if(abs.inputName.equals(name)){
>                 encap.setName(abs.inputName);
>                 System.out.println(""+encap.getName());
>                 abs.flag = 1;
>             }
>         }
>         if(abs.flag!=1){
>             System.out.println("Name doesn't exist..");
>         }
>         else{
>             abs.abscompute();
>         }
> ```

This would be easier to read as a method call:

```
        if (validName(inputName)) {
            greeting.setGreeting(inputName);
            sequence.generate();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Name doesn't exist..");
        }
```

Then instead of

```
                abs.flag = 1;
            }
        }
```

You could say

```
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

There are other places with similar feedback, but perhaps you should take a try at it yourself.